# Android barcode scanner - alternatives to zxing?

Tags: android, barcode

I'm looking for an alternative barcode scanner for Android. I need it to be:

- Fast
- Smooth
- Compatible with portrait mode

Comment: Refer to my answer here for the Latest Alternative to Zxing for Barcode Scanning.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418792/android-barcode-scanner/32391107#32391107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off chance that your emphasis is portrait-mode, rather than not-zxing, then you can try the (for-pay) version of Barcode Scanner, called [Barcode Scanner+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android), which does scanning in any orientation among other things.

Answer (score 2):

... or if you really mean a scanner that is not based on the same code, then look to the ones that predate zxing. These are things like [QuickMark](https://market.android.com/details?id=tw.com.quickmark), [i-nigma](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.threegvision.products.inigma.Android), [BeeTagg](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.connvision.mobileaccessor.android), [NeoReader](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.gavitec.android), and [ScanLife](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ScanLife).

Answer (score 0):

Check [ShopSavvy](http://www.shopsavvy.com/developers/)

Comment: And this is also based on zxing.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Goggles.](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text)

[Google Shopper.](http://www.google.com/mobile/shopper/)

Comment: Both of these use zxing too, as it's from Google as well. I think the OP wants something not based on the same code.

Answer (score -1):

[IxMat](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ixellence.ixmat.android.community&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5peGVsbGVuY2UuaXhtYXQuYW5kcm9pZC5jb21tdW5pdHkiXQ..)