# i-nigma library integration in ANDROID

Tags: android, integration, barcode, scanning

I have to use i-nigma library for barcode scanning in an Android app. On Google i found that the library is not open source, so one will have to get the license.

If someone has done this before, please let me know if they provide documentation along with the license. If not, then how complex or easy the integration is.

Comment: You have to contact to 3GVision support:http://www.i-nigma.com/qr-barcode-reader-sdk.html I think they will help you with integration of SDK .

Comment: You can use Google Provided Barcode Scanning Classes as an alternative. Refer my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418792/android-barcode-scanner/32391107#32391107

Comment: @Sushrita yes they do provide documentation and a sample application. :)