# Barcode Scanning issue in Samsung tab device in android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am working on one of my android Project in which i have implemented Famous Zbar barcode scanner as follows

```
surfaceViewFlash = (SurfaceView) mView.findViewById(R.id.PREVIEW);
            surfaceViewFlash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            surfaceViewFlash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mCameraScanner = getCameraInstance();
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            previewingScanner = true;
            autoFocusHandlerScanner = new Handler();


            // Instance barcode zBarScanner
            zBarScanner = new ImageScanner();
            zBarScanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
            zBarScanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);


            mPreviewScanner = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCameraScanner, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
            preview.addView(mPreviewScanner);

            if (barcodeScanned) {
                barcodeScanned = false;
                mCameraScanner.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                mCameraScanner.startPreview();
                previewingScanner = true;

                mCameraScanner.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);

                Log.e("initControls", "initControls");
}
```

/**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     */

```
  public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return c;
    }

  private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCameraScanner != null) {
            mCameraScanner.cancelAutoFocus();
            previewingScanner = false;
            mCameraScanner.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mPreviewScanner.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreviewScanner);
            mCameraScanner.stopPreview();
            mCameraScanner.release();
            mCameraScanner = null;
            mPreviewScanner = null;
        }
    }




public Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                if (previewingScanner) {
                    handlerForAutoFocus.postDelayed(doAutoFocus,2000);
                    Camera.Parameters parameters = null;
                    mCameraScanner=mCameraScanner.open();
                    if (null != mCameraScanner.getParameters()) {
                        parameters = mCameraScanner.getParameters();
                    }
                    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
                    if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                        mCameraScanner.setParameters(parameters);
                        mCameraScanner.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("doAutoFocus", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    public Camera.PreviewCallback previewCb = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

                Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
                barcode.setData(data);

                int result = zBarScanner.scanImage(barcode);

                if (result != 0) {
                    previewingScanner = false;
                    mCameraScanner.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    mCameraScanner.stopPreview();

                    SymbolSet syms = zBarScanner.getResults();

                    for (Symbol sym : syms) {


                        /*Log.i("<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>> ","<<<<Bar Code>>> " + sym.getData());*/
                        String scanResult = sym.getData().trim();
                        int type = sym.getType();


                        BarcodeFormat name = BarcodeFormat.getFormatById(type);
                        String nameOfBarcode = name.getName();
                        DataToPref.setSharedPreferanceData(getActivity(), BarcodeConstant.SCANNEDMESSAGE, scanResult + "");
                        //                    showMessage(getActivity(), getString(R.string.app_name), scanResult + " " + nameOfBarcode);
                        showMessage(getActivity(), getString(R.string.app_name), scanResult + "");
                        barcodeScanned = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            autoFocusHandlerScanner.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 2000);
        }
    };
```

The above code works fine in many devices, like nexus 5, samsung core and many more. Recently I was testing the app in my Samsung Tab but I am getting error somewhere here

```
 mCameraScanner=mCameraScanner.open();
                    if (null != mCameraScanner.getParameters()) {
                        parameters = mCameraScanner.getParameters();
                    }
```

Error is

An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
09-02 13:16:39.357  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
09-02 13:16:39.367  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
09-02 13:16:39.367  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:419)
09-02 13:16:39.367  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:389)
09-02 13:16:39.367  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at com.hyper.barcodeapp.fragment.ScannerFragment$4.run(ScannerFragment.java:425)
09-02 13:16:39.367  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-02 13:16:39.377  14292-14292/com.hyper.barcodeapp W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

can anyone help me to solve this issue? I get black screen in scanner area.

Comment: You should rather try new Barcode Scanning Api available via GooglePlayServices 7.8 version. Refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418792/android-barcode-scanner/32391107#32391107 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the correct permissions...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```